# operator & cannot be applied to operands of type int and bool when using bitwise and

Tags: c#

If I have the following C# code:

```
int i = 1;
bool b = true;

if (i & 1 == 1 && b)
    ...
```

I get an error:

```
operator & cannot be applied to operands of type int and bool
```

I can do:

```
if (i & 1 == 1)
```

and

```
if (b)
```

I have tried putting them in brackets:

```
if ((i & 1 == 1) && b)
if (i & 1 == 1 && (b))
if ((i & 1 == 1) && (b))
```

but it made no difference.

What am I missing here?

I know I can just put them in separate ifs, but I'm trying to understand what's going on here.  Is it a bug?

I'm using VS 2015.  Target framework is 4.6.2.

Comment: `if ((i & 1) == 1 && b)`?

Comment: Thanks Sami - that did the trick

Comment: [Precedence and Order of Evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: It's because it will execute like following: `if(i & (1 == 1) && b)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precedence rules; `==` is higher than `&` or `&&`; so in the left expression (`i & 1 == 1`) you actually mean: `(i & 1) == 1`. Then the combined expression is:

```
if ((i & 1) == 1 && b)
```

Actually, it is odd that you say this works:

```
if (i & 1 == 1)
```

because I get CS0019 "Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'" for that!

Comment: You're right `if (i & 1 == 1)` does not work, but my slow PC takes time to flag it as an error, so assumed it was good in my quick tests.

Comment: @Graham Check compiler errors, intellisense can fail sometimes.